# Django rest Framework error messages. Does not work

Tags: python, django, django-models, error-handling

I am new to Django and I am working on a small project, I want an error message to be shown if the user let the field empty. the code that I wrote is not working. Can anyone help me ?

```
 def validate_name(school: School):
    if school.name is None:
      raise APIException(detail='Name is mandatory.')

 class SchoolService(object):
  @staticmethod
  def validate_create(school: School):
    validate_name(school)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Rest Framework provides default messages for such common wanted behaviours.

You do not even need to add anything to your field as fields are `required` by default, unless you explicitly specify `required=False`

If the user does not fill that field, DRF will automatically return a json object mentioning the field is required and should be filled.

[see docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required)

Answer (score 0):

In your serializer class try adding the validation this way

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_name(self, value):
   if value is None:
       raise serializers.ValidationError('Name is mandatory')
   return value
```